# Output haskell object omitting 'show' declarations

Tags: haskell, io

How could I output Haskell object as a string that is valid Haskell code to the output omitting existing `show` declarations?

For example, I have following types declarations and corresponding `show` declarations ([check the code out in an online IDE](https://ideone.com/PSAPKY)):

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeSynonymInstances, FlexibleInstances #-}

import Data.Maybe

type VersionCompound = Maybe Int

data VersionNumber = VersionNumber [VersionCompound] deriving (Show)

data MaturityLevel = Dev
                   | Test
                   | User
                   | ReleaseCandidate
                   | Prod
                   deriving (Show)

data Version = MaturityVersion MaturityLevel VersionNumber  
     | Version VersionNumber

class ToString a where
    toString :: a -> String

instance ToString VersionCompound where
    toString (Just n) = (show n)
    toString Nothing = "x"

instance ToString [VersionCompound] where
    toString [] = "" 
    toString (x:[]) = (toString x)
    toString (x:xs) = (toString x) ++ "." ++ (toString xs) 

instance ToString VersionNumber where
    toString (VersionNumber []) = "" 
    toString (VersionNumber (x:[])) = (toString x) 
    toString (VersionNumber (x:xs)) = (toString x) ++ "." ++ (toString xs)

instance ToString Version where
    toString (MaturityVersion maturityLevel versionNumber) = (show maturityLevel) ++ "/" ++ (toString versionNumber)
    toString (Version versionNumber) = (toString versionNumber)

instance Show Version where
    show version = toString version

main = putStrLn $ show (Version $ VersionNumber [ Just 1, Just 2, Nothing])
```

Output of this program is:

```
1.2.x
```

But is there any way to output object as is in a form of valid Haskell code? For example, for the code above `showIntact $ Version $ VersionNumber [ Just 1, Just 2, Nothing]` would output something like:

```
Version ( VersionNumber [ Just 1, Just 2, Nothing] )
```

Comment: Add `deriving (Show)` to your data declaration. Do not overwrite `Show`. Write another function `versionNumber :: Version -> String` for nonstandard `show`ing.

Comment: `print $ Version $ VersionNumber [ Just 1, Just 2, Nothing]` should work if you add `deriving Show` to the `Version` type, as you did for the others.

Comment: @chi: in this case it complains about `Duplicate instance declarations`

Comment: Oops I did not see the last `Show Version` instance. Is there any reason why you want to keep that instance instead of the default one?

Comment: I just figured that I don't need to keep `Show Version` instance indeed. And that solves my problem of 'exporting' object into Haskell representation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define your own function:

```
showIntact :: Version -> String
showIntact (Version v) = "Version " ++ show v
showIntact (MaturityVersion ml vn) = "MaturityVersion " ++ show ml ++ " " ++ show vn
```

You can then use `putStrLn $ showIntact $ ....`.